# Branch point versus points along branch cut

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers, branch-cuts, branch-points

I am trying to get better intuition for branch points and a branch cut.  I understand the textbook definitions:

*Branch point* (of an analytic function $f$):  Point in the complex plane whose value in the domain of $f$ takes on multiple values in the range of $f$. (Taken from [here](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/BranchPoint.html))

*Branch cut* (of an analytic function $f$):  Points in the complex plane along which the function $f$ is discontinuous. (Taken from [here](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/BranchCut.html).)

So, now when I look at the function $f(z)=log(z)$, and I see that for any value along the negative real axis in the complex plane $z$, I get two *distinctly different* points in the plane for $f(z)$.  This tells me that all of the points $z\in(-\infty,0]$ are branch points, and they also form a set of points corresponding to a branch cut: $z\in(-\infty,0]$.

From what I am seeing, $z=-1$ is also a branch point because it corresponds to two distinctly different points on the $f(z)$ plane:  In polar, $z=-1=-e^{i\pi}=-e^{-i\pi}$.  and when I map these to $f(z)=log(z)$, I'm getting the following: $f(-e^{i\pi})=log(-e^{i\pi})=ln|-e^{i\pi}|+i*arg(-e^{i\pi})$. and since $ln|-e^{i\pi}|=0$, and $arg(-e^{i\pi})=i\pi$, then we get $f(-e^{i\pi})=i\pi$.  Similarly,

$$f(-e^{-i\pi})=log(-e^{-i\pi})=ln|-e^{-i\pi}|+i*arg(-e^{-i\pi})$$.

and since $ln|-e^{i\pi}|=0$, and $arg(-e^{-i\pi})=-i\pi$, then we get $f(-e^{-i\pi})=-i\pi$.

So, for one $z$ value $z=-1$, I am getting two different values for $f(z)$: 
$f(-e^{-i\pi})=-i\pi$
$f(-e^{i\pi})=i\pi$

Can someone please help me understand why only the point $z=0$ is considered a branch point, and not, for example $z=-1$?

Comment: At a branch point the function cannot be defined analytically on a neighborhood - but the branch cut is usually fairly arbitrary up to some general conditions, so for the logarithm you need to connect zero and infinity (the 2 branch points) by a simple curve which can be a ray like the negative axis or the positive axis, but can be be a spiral too for example. So for $-1$ you just use a branch cut avoiding it and you get  analytic logarithm on a neighborhood of $-1$

Comment: I'm not understanding how this answers my question: 1) you give the definition "the function cannot be defined analytically on a neighborhood " for branch cut.  So, are you saying the Wolfram alpha definition is wrong?  2) This still doesn't tell me why all of the other points along the branch cut are not ALSO branch points.

Comment: that's the definition for the branch point - it is a point $w$ where a function cannot be defined analytically in a neighborhood of it (even excluding $w$) , but it can be defined analytically anywhere near it (the branch point $w$ has a neighborhood $U$ s.t for any $z \in U, z \ne w$, the function can be defined analytically in a  small neighborhood of $z$ (which obviously won't include $w$) - note that a branch point is not an isolated singularity in the usual sense but it is not an accumulation point of singularities either. Branch cuts are fairly arbitrary up to some constraints.

Comment: rigorously you need to talk about germs of analytic functions, path continuation etc, but the main idea imho is that branch points are given and isolated (though again they are not isolated singularities) while branch cuts which allow the defintion of $f$ on a "widest" posiible domain are rather arbitrary, so for the logarithm for example, you can cut the positive imaginary axis out (which allows an analytic logarithm to be defined on both the positive and negative reals at the same time), but you can never define the logarithm in a full neighborhood of zero even excluding it

Comment: Still not getting it I'm afraid.  So, then why is $z=0$ a branch point of $log(z)$, when I can easily draw a neighborhood around $z=0$ with radius $1$, which would include the point $z=1$.  And, $log(1)$ is single valued.  So, I just found a neighborhood around $z=0$, such that it includes a point that is single-valued.  If I understand what you're saying, this now makes $z=0$ NOT a branch point anymore.  Is that right?

Comment: that's the point that you cannot define the logarithm even continuously not to speak analytically on a neighborhood of zero (which excludes zero), but you need to cut a simple curve (usually segment) starting at zero from that neighborhood - it is not about being single-valued, but about being a continuos (and then it follows analytic) single valued function on the neighborhood; sure you can define single valued logarithms at any point around zero (say on the unit circle) but you cannot do it in a continuos (hence analyitc) way